# Proper grammar for injecting another person with a drug?

Tags: grammar

I'm looking for the grammatical way to say one person gave another person an injection of some illegal drug, as opposed to a medical-office situation.  Self-injection is described  when a person says "I [or he] shot up."

Should I use "I shot him up," which sounds rather violent, or is there a better form?

Answer (score 1):

How about [drugged](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/drug)? It isn't exclusive to injection, but "Administer a drug to (someone) in order to induce stupor or insensibility" sounds close to what you are looking for.

Comment: Grammatically solid, but I was hoping for something more slangy.

Comment: Oh, then you might want [doped](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dope?q=doped#dope__15). It's certainly more slangy.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that you "dosed" him with the drug.